# AWS ParallelCluster Graviton Rest API Connection Refused

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jwt, slurm, amazon-parallelcluster

I am trying to follow a tutorial using AWS ParallelCluster ([AWS Research Workshop](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-research-workshops)) and once I get CloudFormation up and running, I cannot connect to the cluster via the Rest API. I am using Slurm 21.08.8 and ParallelCluster 3.1.4. I am able to SSH into the head node and kick off jobs, but when I try to access the Node via SageMaker notebook, I get a connection refused. Below is my configuration YAML for ParallelCluster. Please take note that this is using the Graviton2 ARM processors:

```yaml
Region: ${REGION}
Image:
  Os: alinux2
SharedStorage:
  - Name: myebs
    StorageType: Ebs
    MountDir: /shared
    EbsSettings:
      VolumeType: gp2
      Size: 200
HeadNode:
  InstanceType: c6g.medium
  Networking:
    SubnetId: ${SUBNET_ID}
    ElasticIp: true 
  Ssh:
    KeyName: ${KEY_NAME}
  CustomActions:
    OnNodeConfigured:
      Script: ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_LOCATION}
      Args:
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_1}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_2}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_3}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_4}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_5}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_6}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_7}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_8}
        - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_9}
  Iam:
    AdditionalIamPolicies:
      - Policy: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecretsManagerReadWrite
    S3Access:
      - EnableWriteAccess: true
        BucketName: '*'
Scheduling:
  Scheduler: slurm
  SlurmQueues:
    - Name: q1
      CapacityType: ONDEMAND
      ComputeResources:
        - Name: cr1
          InstanceType: c6g.2xlarge
          MinCount: 0
          MaxCount: 20
          Efa:
            Enabled: false
      CustomActions:
        OnNodeConfigured:
          Script: ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_LOCATION}
          Args:
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_1}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_2}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_3}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_4}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_5}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_6}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_7}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_8}
            - ${POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_ARGS_9}
      Iam:
        AdditionalIamPolicies:
          - Policy: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecretsManagerReadWrite
        S3Access:
          - EnableWriteAccess: true
            BucketName: '*'
      Networking:
        SubnetIds:
          - ${SUBNET_ID}
        AssignPublicIp: true
        PlacementGroup:
          Enabled: true
```

Here is my `slurm.conf`:

```
#
# Example slurm.conf file. Please run configurator.html
# (in doc/html) to build a configuration file customized
# for your environment.
#
#
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
#
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
# CLUSTER SETTINGS
ClusterName=mypc6g2
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmctldPort=6820-6829
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm.state
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SwitchType=switch/none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
ReconfigFlags=KeepPartState
#
# CLOUD CONFIGS OPTIONS
SlurmctldParameters=idle_on_node_suspend,power_save_min_interval=30,cloud_dns
CommunicationParameters=NoAddrCache
SuspendProgram=/opt/parallelcluster/scripts/slurm/slurm_suspend
ResumeProgram=/opt/parallelcluster/scripts/slurm/slurm_resume
ResumeFailProgram=/opt/parallelcluster/scripts/slurm/slurm_suspend
SuspendTimeout=120
ResumeTimeout=1800
PrivateData=cloud
ResumeRate=0
SuspendRate=0
#
# TIMERS
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=180
UnkillableStepTimeout=180
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
MessageTimeout=60
#
# SCHEDULING, JOB, AND NODE SETTINGS
EnforcePartLimits=ALL
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
MpiDefault=none
ReturnToService=1
TaskPlugin=task/affinity,task/cgroup
#
# TRES AND GPU CONFIG OPTIONS
GresTypes=gpu
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU
#
# LOGGING
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#
# WARNING!!! The slurm_parallelcluster.conf file included
# get updated by pcluster process, be careful
# when manually editing!
include slurm_parallelcluster.conf
# Enable jwt auth for Slurmrestd
AuthAltTypes=auth/jwt
#
## /opt/slurm/etc/slurm.conf
#
# ACCOUNTING
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
#
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageHost=<IP ADDRESS> # cluster headnode's DNS
AccountingStorageUser=db_user
AccountingStoragePort=6839
```

Here is the output of `sudo journalctl -u slurmrestd` (hiding IP):

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2022-05-12 10:46:45 UTC, end at Thu 2022-05-26 03:00:38 UTC. --
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: Started Slurm restd daemon.
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  _establish_config_source: using config_file=/opt/slurm/etc/slurmrestd.conf (environment)
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  slurm_conf_init: using config_file=/opt/slurm/etc/slurmrestd.conf
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  Reading slurm.conf file: /opt/slurm/etc/slurmrestd.conf
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  NodeNames=q1-dy-cr1-[1-20] setting Sockets=8 based on CPUs(8)/(CoresPerSocket(1)/ThreadsPerCore(1))
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: slurmrestd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: Unit slurmrestd.service entered failed state.
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: slurmrestd.service failed.
```

Here is the output of `sudo systemctl status slurmrestd` (hiding IP):

```
● slurmrestd.service - Slurm restd daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/slurmrestd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2022-05-25 22:30:25 UTC; 4h 31min ago
 Main PID: 12872 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: Started Slurm restd daemon.
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  _establish_config_source: using config_file=/opt/slurm/etc/slurmrestd.conf (environment)
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  slurm_conf_init: using config_file=/opt/slurm/etc/slurmrestd.conf
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  Reading slurm.conf file: /opt/slurm/etc/slurmrestd.conf
May 25 22:30:25 slurmrestd[12872]: debug:  NodeNames=q1-dy-cr1-[1-20] setting Sockets=8 based on CPUs(8)/(CoresPerSocket(1)/ThreadsPerCore(1))
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: slurmrestd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: Unit slurmrestd.service entered failed state.
May 25 22:30:25 systemd[1]: slurmrestd.service failed.
```

Here is the output of `systemctl status slurmctld`:

```
● slurmctld.service - Slurm controller daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/slurmctld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-05-25 22:30:25 UTC; 4h 33min ago
 Main PID: 12899 (slurmctld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/slurmctld.service
           ├─12899 /opt/slurm/sbin/slurmctld -D
           └─12903 slurmctld: slurmscriptd

May 26 00:00:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 00:20:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 00:40:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 01:00:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 01:20:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 01:40:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 02:00:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 02:20:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 02:40:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
May 26 03:00:01 slurmctld[12899]: slurmctld: auth/jwt: auth_p_token_generate: created token for root for 1800 seconds
```

I cannot get the `slurmrestd` service up and running and am not sure where else to look since this is not super well documented on the Slurm site and the Rest API is not a supported feature of AWS ParallelCluster (according to the AWS Support team).

I am running the follow block of code from the tutorial:

```py
import requests
import json

slurm_openapi_ep = 'http://'+slurm_host+':8082/openapi/v3'
print(slurm_openapi_ep)
# slurm_rest_base='http://'+slurm_host+':8082/slurm/v0.0.35'
# slurm_rest_base='http://'+slurm_host+':8082/slurm/v0.0.36'
# slurm_rest_base='http://'+slurm_host+':8082/slurm/v0.0.37'

_, get_headers = pcluster_helper.update_header_token()

print(get_headers)

resp_api = requests.get(slurm_openapi_ep, headers=get_headers)
print(resp_api)

if resp_api.status_code != 200:
    # This means something went wrong.
    print("Error" , resp_api.status_code)

with open('build/slurm_api.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(resp_api.json(), outfile)

print(json.dumps(resp_api.json(), indent=2))
```

with an `print` output of:

```
http://<HEAD NODE IP ADDRESS HERE>:8082/openapi/v3
{'X-SLURM-USER-NAME': 'ec2-user', 'X-SLURM-USER-TOKEN': '<MY TOKEN HERE>', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
```

and an error of:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='<HEAD NODE IP ADDRESS HERE>', port=8082): Max retries exceeded with url: /openapi/v3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe6151b9940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or ideas to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to find an answer to this—AWS updated their documentation and tutorial to support the Graviton processors. Works like a charm now.